# Available frameworks/tools to send change notifications?

Tags: c#, notifications, delta

Is there a framework that will identify (through comparing the object) when an object property value has changed (user can specify which properties to "watch") and then raise an event/send a notification?

Example:  The app stores Person class in a database and keeps a copy in memory.  The app  retrieves the person data from the database to refresh the copy in memory periodically.  Other apps/processes update the person data in the database.  I want an event/notification raised when the mood property(list collection of strings: Upbeat,tired, etc.) of the person object  is changed.

I know how to code this, but I get the feeling there is something out there that does this.  Only two things I can think of that is similar is:

- cache notifications, but haven't seen any that allow you to specify which 
  properties/values to notify on.  This  would also require one to have a distributed cache server.
- sql query notifications - I'm looking into this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description of the issue sounds a lot like what happens when you work with Entity Framework (and other ORMs).  It's possible you could use the Entity Framework, and inspect the objects after they have been processed to detect changes.  An example of which you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456854.aspx).

Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

EDIT:

Regarding the Sql Query Notifications, take a look at the [SqlDependency Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) if you want to head down that route.